# Get count by unique values in a column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a schema like: `(parent, child, item, frequency)`

The same parent can have multiple child and different child can have repeating item with the repeating frequency. e.g.

```
PA    CA   IA  FA
PA    CB   IA  FA
PA    CB   IB  FB
```

Note that CA and CB both have one common item.

So, now I want all distinct parents along with sum of frequencies. e.g. for the above table the answer is PA,(FA+FB). (NOTE: not 2*FA+FB).

I tried with the following SQL query but that is giving me 2*FA+FB.

```
SELECT distinct [parent], sum(frequency) as freq
FROM [sampleDB].[dbo].[sampleTable]
group by [parent]
order by freq DESC
```

That makes sense as distinct is over parent and not on query. Noting the mistake, then I tried with

```
SELECT distinct [parent], sum(frequency from (Select distinct [item], [frequency])) as freq
FROM [sampleDB].[dbo].[sampleTable]
group by [parent]
order by freq DESC
```

But that is giving syntactical errors. What should be the correct query?

Comment: Could you show us an example result set you are expecting?

Comment: yes, as given in question too. For the table given, I need the result set as `PA, (FA+FB)` as PA has actually two items and their frequency sum up to FA + FB.

Comment: Why is this tagged under mysql?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you need this:

```
SELECT parent, SUM(frequency) AS freq
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT parent, item, frequency FROM sampleTable) AS t 
GROUP BY parent
ORDER BY freq DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
SELECT parent, sum(frequency) FROM (SELECT DISTINCT parent, frequency FROM table_name) GROUP BY parent
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to first summarize at the parent/item level, then sum the frequencies:

```
select parent, sum(frequency)
from (select distinct parent, item, frequency
      from sampletable st
     ) st
group by parent;
```